# Why is the silver nitrate chemical test more favorable than that of sodium iodide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, halides, reactivity

Two tests to determine the presence of alkyl chlorides are the [silver nitrate in 1% ethanol and sodium iodide in 15% acetone](http://academics.wellesley.edu/Chemistry/chem211lab/Orgo_Lab_Manual/Appendix/ClassificationTests/halide.html) tests.  These two tests both produce a precipitate when added to chloride ions (AgCl and NaCl respectively).

NaI in acetone must often be heated to 50ºC for several minutes to produce a visible precipitate.  In contrast, $ \ce{AgNO3} $ typically does not require heat and immediately produces a visible precipitate.

Why is the silver reaction so much more favorable than that of sodium?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/why-are-nacl-and-nabr-not-soluble-whereas-nai-is-soluble-in-acetone-in-the-fin